# android : developer options hidden

Tags: android

I'm using an android device (asus tf701t) and I want to enable developer options.

This procedure is not working : Settings - About - Tap into build number 7 times.
The "toast" message never appeared.

What other options must be enabled to make it work ?
I have a keyboard plugged with the tablet, is there a compatibility problem with it ?

I did what is in this video : [enable developer options](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6FkhSeiYd8)

Comment: you have to tap 8 times. and also refer to the white paper for your model of android device.

Comment: I tried 7 - 8 - 10 - and 20 times but it is not working

Comment: What version of Android are you running?

Comment: Android Version 4.2.2

Comment: @icewall0 have to try looking in your user manual or white paper for the same device?

Comment: In user manual, they are explanations about how to load battery and some other legal stuff but nothing about developer options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 options with the same final name which create a big confusion...

I found the solution in French : 
Paramètres - A propos - Informations logicielles - Numéro de Build

Which is in English (I suppose) : 
Settings - About - Software information - Build Number

There is a confusion because I tried 7 times on : 
Paramètres - A propos - Numéro de build

instead of :
Paramètres - A propos - Informations logicielles - Numéro de Build

I hope that can help someone else having the same problem

Comment: Thanks for this - I have a Lenovo Tablet with Android 10, and this was also the problem for me. (Build number in two places, both showing the 'you are 3 taps away from being a developer' messages, but only one of them actually switching on the developer mode.)

Answer (score 4):

According to [android documents](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) these are the options

```
On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.
On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.
Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.
```

You **should tap to Build Number** 7 times. Also according to a comment, if you have enabled 'magnification gestures', then the 7 taps does not work. You have to disable that accessibility first

Comment: this does not provide the answer at all. as he has mentioned that he has tried to tap 7 times and it did not solve the problem

Comment: I showed all possible ways from developer.android.com for his "What other options must be enabled to work" question, and added the information about disabling gestures. I think answer looks quite helpful

Comment: I tried the procedure with or without each accessibility option (enable or disable). I change to English language too but it is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the owner/admin of the device?

I have the same problem. I'm using a separate account to logon to the device. Tapping 7 times (or more) does **not** work.
There is also an owner/admin account on the device. But I cannot test it with that account.

Check: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2564240 They refer to using the primary profile.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one user you need to be logged in as the first, main user. Otherwise tapping doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Thing is that I was trying to unlock the developer options on my daughter's phone. I had installed Family Link that, which prevents access to a lot of stuff including developer options on her phone. Solution: Go to your phone, enter family link, choose the profile attached to the phone that you want to unlock (her phone) and, on configurations, enable developer options. That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Today I was having same problem. But I found out the problem over the web and it was the very different way. Till now I have open developer option in number of devices and it was pretty straight forward. But the device with model M3 SM15 was creating the same problem. Tapping on build was not producing developer options. Then I dialed below code then developer option screen got visible. The code was as mentioned below.

**Run dial-up application and type ‘*#991#’.**

After spending time, I finally sorted out this. Hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

**What produce this bug, it's because no any (google) account connected-synced with the device.**

*I used a trick after "TWRP factory resset" to skip entire "SETUP WIZARD".*
*(oh yeah, this enforced "setup wizard"(!), when you first boot your device, who enforce-fully exposes everything to google, just before you can manage those permissions through settings!)*

So, in short, after above trick, the device can start without the shitty "wizard setup" and allows you to manually setting up the device (before you connect).

What produce this bug, **it's because no any (google) account connected-synced with the device**.